# Strict Bounds for Google Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Issue: When I use Google Geocoding API to geocode the address: "*Holyoke Center 1350 Massachusetts Ave*" it returns the lat,lng of somewhere in Holyoke, MA. However, what I meant is the Holyoke Center whose address is *1350 Massachusetts Ave*. If I remove "*Ave*" from the query, Google does point to the Holyoke Center that I want.

What I have done: I have tried to set `bounds` field to the city Cambridge, MA, but it doesn't work because it is not a "strict" bound. Results from other cities will still be shown, and it did. This is what I queried:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=HOLYOKE+CENTER+1350+MASSACHUSETTS+AVE&bounds=34.172684,-118.604794|34.236144,-118.500938&sensor=false

Is there a way for us to disambiguate the address or restrict the search to a particular city? Note that it should work for all addresses. The address above is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

HOLYOKE CENTER is not part of the address.  That should only be part of a query to the Places API, not the geocoder. The geocoder will work if you give it a valid *address* http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1350%20Massachusetts%20Ave,%20Cambridge,%20MA&sensor=false

Comment: But if I supply just "HOLYOKE CENTER", it still works. Also, I want my app to be able to understand "Holyoke Center" as a premise because Google actually knows but it is just confused it with Holyoke, MA for some reason.

Comment: You probably want to use the Places API then, not the geocoder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is just one example. I have addresses like say 44 JFK Street, Cambridge, MA. Does Places API take care of such addresses?

Comment: [Seems to](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=44%20JFK%20Street,%20Cambridge,%20MA&place=1)